# MySQL Select from multiple tables and create a new table

Tags: mysql, node.js, select

How can i get the desired output in MySQL:

```
Column name1
ID Right Wrong
1   3      4
2   5      2

Column name2
ID Right Wrong
1    3     2
2    1     1

Result:
Name   Total_Right  Total_Wrong
name1     8              6
name2     4              3
```

I want to use select and join statements to get the desired result but i am not sure how can i do that.

So, far, i tried it to do with node.js with this:

```
app.get('/processAllStats',function(req,res)
{
    var name=[];
    var stats=[];
    var a='';
    connection.query('select username from user_login',function(err,user){
    if(err) 
        console.log('Error: '+err);
    else
    {
       for(var i=1;i<user.length;i++)
       {
          name.push(user[i].username);
          connection.query('select sum(no_right) as all_right,sum(no_wrong) as all_wrong from '+name[i-1],function(err,rank){   
stats.push(rank[0]);
          });
       }    
    }
});
});
```

Please Help!!

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: The question appears to be off-topic, because questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I wanted to do this in combination with node.js. So, I queried separately and tried to make a new array of desired result, but, I think, due to it being asynchronous, the for loop is not executed in desired manner, and i get an error.

Comment: Just use a `UNION` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION`

```
SELECT 'name1' AS Name, SUM(Right) AS Total_Right, SUM(Wrong) AS Total_Wrong
FROM name1
UNION
SELECT 'name2' AS Name, SUM(Right) AS Total_Right, SUM(Wrong) AS Total_Wrong
FROM name2
```